# dompdf table width issue on page break

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have two div's each of the same width, the right div has more data than the left div. Right div's data table changes its width on a page break. After the page break, the width of the table increases.
I need a solution quickly, can anyone help?

I have used style attributes page-break-after and page-break-before and page break-inside but nothing is working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it right that you build your HTML like a table column by column?

Maybe it would be better to render each row in its own div.
So the break would only before or after a narrow item and not within your tall main wrapper.

Comment: is it possible to change your html structure to row based layout? I think the problem is the div around your table, so your table breaks, but the div around also and the sizes and spaces not fit like you want.